# Clamav with windows

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, clamav

```
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
E: Aborting install. when using --fix-missing.
```

I did `apt-get clean` and tried to re install and it says aborting. I did update and update is broken too.

How do I scan using Ubuntu shell with Ubuntu from Windows store. I was able to install and open ppp just to see if I could install anything.

I have Ubuntu made easy but it says very little about terminal navigating. Fedora 7 Linux bible says a lot about navigating through `bash`. Does Fedora and Ubuntu share commands or will they be different?

Answer (score 0):

There's insufficient information in your question to say anything about your `apt` problems (btw, `apt` has a friendlier interface than `apt-get`).

However, to answer your last question: `bash` is `bash`, and all `sh` descendants are mostly similar: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell) . Note that there are mostly-superficial differences in default filesystem layout between Ubuntu (a Debian distro) and Fedora (a Redhat distro). For information about the common layout, see [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

Comment: E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/clamav/clamav_0.99.4+addedllvm-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]. maybe I don't have p2p enabled? idk I just got into messing with bash a couple months ago.

Comment: Im guessing here. But, isn't Fedora better for command line and or network security, Ubuntu better for GUI based system, and OpenSUSE better for opening things? Im basing that off OpenSUSE kinda sounds like open sesame. But I have Ubuntu made easy and fedora 7 bible.

Comment: @serverfarm1 Believe it or not, that URL above was formatted correctly. If you browse the [index here](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/clamav/), you will see that the package truly does not exist. It's just HTTP. Something is very wrong with `apt` (the particular tool that you are using) for it to try to download a non-existent package. Since you're using the app and not the "real" OS, I'd just start over at this point with a fresh copy.

Comment: @serverfarm1 And in regards to the strengths and weaknesses of the distributions you mention: No, that is not accurate. Learning the history of Linux distributions is general may help you to conceptualize what a distro is, and what components they share (everything you are talking about is in the "userland"; `bash` and other tools come from GNU). That should give you enough to start your research.

Comment: can anybody send me fedora?

Comment: oh yeah soz guys. I did sudo apt-update again and it worked this time.